# how to make this IF statement work

Tags: python

```
fgrades=["90","70","63","81","49"]   
a=0
b=0    
c=0    
d=0    
f=0    
grades=raw_input("enter your final grade: ")    
fgrade+=(grades,)

for i in range(len(fgrades)):
   if fgrades[i]>="90":
      a+=1        
   elif fgrades[i]>="80":
      b+=1        
   elif fgrades[i]>="70":
       c+=1        
   elif fgrades[i]>="60":
       d+=1        
   else:
       f+=1

print a,"\n",b,"\n",c,"\n",d,"\n",f
```

After I put all the things in all the numbers turn in to F. This happens even when you put 96 in as input.

Comment: What is your input? Also the line `fgrade+=(grades,)` should probably use a variable that exists if you are adding to it. Did you mean `fgrades`?

Comment: im writing a program that asking a user to put in a number as u see up there, and that number should restore in a list and after that i need to check if the number is an A or b or c or d or f

Comment: Let me rephrase my question: When you see the prompt while debugging, what you you type as an answer? We need to be able to replicate your input.

Answer (score 2):

A problem i can see here is that you are trying to perform inequalities on strings, rather than numbers. Try typecasting your input values into integers.

If you store the values in fgrades as integers, eg [90, 70, 60, 88, 96] then this should work:

```
fgrades=[90, 70, 60, 88, 96]

a=0

b=0

c=0

d=0

f=0

grades=raw_input("enter your final grade: ")

# Clean up grades, and convert to an integer
grades = int(grades.strip().replace(" ","")

fgrades.append(grades)

for i in range(len(fgrades)):

   if fgrades[i]>=90:
      a+=1        
   elif fgrades[i]>=80:
      b+=1        
   elif fgrades[i]>=70:
       c+=1        
   elif fgrades[i]>=60:
       d+=1        
   else:
       f+=1

print a,"\n",b,"\n",c,"\n",d,"\n",f
```

Otherwise, if you for some reason require the grades to be stored as strings, eg ["90","70","63","81","49"], then the following should work for you:

```
fgrades= ["90","70","63","81","49"] 

a=0

b=0

c=0

d=0

f=0

grades=raw_input("enter your final grade: ")

# Clean up grades
grades = grades.strip().replace(" ","")

fgrades.append(grades)

for i in range(len(fgrades)):

   if int(fgrades[i])>=90:
      a+=1        
   elif int(fgrades[i])>=80:
      b+=1        
   elif int(fgrades[i])>=70:
       c+=1        
   elif int(fgrades[i])>=60:
       d+=1        
   else:
       f+=1

print a,"\n",b,"\n",c,"\n",d,"\n",f
```

Answer (score 1):

here are some suggestion that you might consider making to your code.

Firstly you can change your for loop statement from

```
for i in range(len(fgrades)):
    ...
```

to

```
for i in fgrades:
    ....
```

and so subsequently, you will just need to do comparision to value `i` instead of  `fgrades[i]`

So your code will be

```
fgrades=[]
a=0
b=0
c=0
d=0
f=0

grades=raw_input("enter your final grade: ")

# Clean up grades, and convert to an integer
grades = int(grades.strip().replace(" ","")

fgrade.append(grades)

for i in fgrade:

   if i>=90:
      a+=1        
   elif i >=80:
      b+=1        
   elif i >=70:
       c+=1        
   elif i >=60:
       d+=1        
   else:
       f+=1

print a,"\n",b,"\n",c,"\n",d,"\n",f
```

Comment: have you pasted the wrong code here... it's the same as @RonRon's and hasn't changed the loop statement

Answer (score 0):

First off, you're trying to do numerical greater than or equal to operations on strings. These must be converted to a number data type (int, float, decimal) if you are comparing numbers.

Second, Andy's comment is corrent as well. `fgrade` doesn't exist as a variable/object yet.

```
fgrades=[]   
a=0
b=0    
c=0    
d=0    
f=0    
grades=int(raw_input("enter your final grade: "))
fgrades += (grades,)

for i in range(len(fgrades)):
   if fgrades[i]>=90:
      a+=1        
   elif fgrades[i]>=80:
      b+=1        
   elif fgrades[i]>=70:
       c+=1        
   elif fgrades[i]>=60:
       d+=1        
   else:
       f+=1

print a,"\n",b,"\n",c,"\n",d,"\n",f
```